# UICollectionView cell: Animation completes immediately

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I've got a UICollection view that has a bunch of cells, when the user presses down on one id like to have it animate a bit. The problem i'm running into is the animation competes with no duration. Its like it just ignores the animate all together.

Heres the code from the collection view. Cells is just the collection of cells that i'm using, I tried doing `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` but I could'nt get the method inside the cell to call. So i created an array and put each cell inside there when they are created.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"Highlighted");
    [[cells objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] shrinkCell:YES];
}
```

And here is the code from inside the cell.m

```
-(void)shrinkCell:(BOOL)shrink{
    NSLog(@"Shrink");


    if (shrink) {


        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0.5
                            options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                         animations:^{
                             self.bg.frame = CGRectOffset(self.bg.frame, 100, 100);
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
}
```

So just to reiterate. The cell does move, it just doesn't animate. Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, it appears you cannot animate things inside UICollectionViewCell for some reason.

Comment: @James Dunay, did you overcome this problem then? Even I am having some similar issues and there seems to be hardly any discussion on this issue anywhere.